# Filtering on a joined table but also including data where the joined & filtered table is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, tags

I have a table with User Information and a table with tag information. The tag table basically has a TagType, a UserID and a value for the tag. I joined the two tables based on the UserID.

Now I want to query a list of all users with the values for the tag with the TagType = 1.

```
SELECT [user].name, [tag].value
FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  tag ON user.id = tag.userid
WHERE [tag].type = 1
```

So far, so good. This works well.

The problem I have now is that I also want to see users in my query that do not have a tag with the Tag Type = 1. In that case it should just return NULL. Right now these users are not returned by the query.

If I get rid of the 'WHERE [tag].id = 1' then they show up but it will return several lines for each user - one for each existing Tag Type - but I don't want that.

In a sense I want to get:

```
Column 1: User Name
Column 2: Tag value of Tag Type 1 if it exists, otherwise NULL
```

I am stuck right there. I don't know how to get the other users in but keep the other tag types out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `WHERE` condition inside the `JOIN` condition.

```
SELECT [user].name, [tag].value
FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  tag ON user.id = tag.userid and [tag].type = 1
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Works like a charm! I hoped is was something easy.

Comment: @MarcoK - Since you already had `LEFT JOIN` in place that was the most logical solution.  Otherwise you would've needed something like `CASE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT [user].name, [tag].value
FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  tag ON user.id = tag.userid AND [tag].type = 1
```